# Identifying attributes from related tables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, relates

I've created a relationship class and created a 1-m relationship between my feature class and table. When identifying the results in ArcGIS 10.2 it returns the details using the `"OBJECTID"` field. Is it possible to query the results and show the `"FlightID"` rather than `"ObjectID"`?

In the example provided in the following, the 7266 (`"OBJECTID"`) would be replaced by 16-284 (`"FlightID"`):

[image: Related Table Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this option in the Table properties. In the tab "Display", change the field of the "Display Expression".

[image: display_expression]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response however I believe the layer properties display tab applies to the feature class itself not to the related table so under the display expression this changes the P_10968 value in the example I provided. I want to be able to change the related value returned (currently object id field) in the related table to the flightid value

Comment: My bad, I meant the TABLE properties. Just follow these instructions for your related table. Table properties --> display tab --> and change display expression to "FlightID"

Comment: Hi, yes if i add the table to the project and goto Table properties --> display tab it is already set on FlightID however it'nt translating through to the identify of the table as a related record. I've created a relationship class to permanently relate the table to the feature class which appears to work correctly however didn't see any options during this process for the display options....

Comment: aha I seem to worked it out I needed to have the table in the TOC. you can then tick 'Show relates with field properties' (right click in the identify window on the 7266 value, thanks for all your help!

Comment: with pleasure, glad it worked :-)